# Gare de Lyon to CDG on November 3-4, 2018

Tags: trains, public-transport, paris, sightseeing

I will be arriving at the Paris Gare de Lyon Train station around 9.30 AM tomorrow (Saturday) and want to explore some major attractions in Paris and then will have to catch an international flight at 9PM from CDG. For that I am planning to put the luggage in a locker at the Gare de Lyon station and then go to eiffel tower and then go to see some more places and then come back to Gare de Lyon to pick up the luggage and then go to CDG to catch the flight. My main concern is how to go back to CDG from Gare de Lyon station. The below links say that there is no RER B on Saturday and the bus line also severely disrupted.

https://www.parisaeroport.fr/en/passengers/access/news/rer-b-disruption-november-4-and-5

https://www.lebusdirect.com/

What are the alternative ways to go back to CDG apart from taking a taxi ?

Is there a day pass which will work for all the lines ?

Comment: Looking at the link you have posted it seems replacement buses will be provided by RER-B. The blue color buses will go till CDG-2 and green colored ones till CDG-1

Comment: catching the replacement bus is not a very good idea in my opinion, he should take the RERB up to Stade de France, then leave the RER and take the bus, in the evening, in a city which he doesn't know well, and in an area like Stade de France which is not the best in town. So I would totally avoid RERB for airport connections that weekend

Comment: The replacement bus is an absolute non-starter.  For sure.

Answer (score 5):

A suggestion to minimize transfers between networks :

1. RER A from *Gare de Lyon* to *Opéra* (*Auber* actually).
2. [RoissyBus](https://www.ratp.fr/plans-lignes/bus-noctilien/roissybus) from *Opéra* to *CDG1* or *CDG2*

For day passes, have a look at [Tarifs Mobilis](https://www.ratp.fr/en/titres-et-tarifs/mobilis).

If you want to use your Mobilis pass for the RoissyBus, you need a zone 1-5 pass.

(Note : the english RATP website is not up to date and RATP's twitter customer support has confirmed that a [Mobilis zone 1-5 pass is valid for RoissyBus](https://twitter.com/ClientsRATP/status/1058301878105239552)).

There seem to be [at least one option for lockers near *Opéra*](https://www.google.com/maps/place/City-Locker/@48.8677241,2.3329071,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x47e66e34719b4699:0x30a26b1da34be887!8m2!3d48.8721776!4d2.3271054). I nevertheless cannot give any feedback on this service that I have never used.

Comment: My variation on this.  Upon arrival at GDLyon, **instantly without hesitation take a taxi with your luggage to Opéra**.  Do not even stop for a cafe etc.  Store luggage at Opéra.  Walk over to the Apple shop etc and have fun all day.  At the end of this day, use the RoissyBus of @audionuma.  Very nice!  *(Caveat, I generally dislike busses and have not tried that particular one.)*

Comment: (+1) I think RoissyBus is now included in Mobilis zone 1-5. The English-language website is not up to date.

Comment: @Relaxed : checking with ratp's twitter customer support. Stay tuned.

Comment: Great, thanks! In the meantime, I found the earlier discussion of the topic which gave me this impression: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/120743/split-ticketing-to-cdg-on-pariss-rer

Comment: Another question : Is there some solution to store luggage in the Opera area?

Comment: Indeed, as @relaxed says when the OP stores the luggage at Opéra, it will have to be somewhere very convenient.   someone with experience will have to provide this inormation